# Can a timing chain issue cause cylinder misfires on one bank, specifically the odd cylinders?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, misfire, camaro

Make: Chevrolet

Model: Camaro

Year: 2010

3.6L v6 LT1

I am experiencing misfires on cylinders three and five. I have replaced spark plugs, swapped cylinder 2,4,6 ignition coils with cylinders 1,3,5 coils. Also all cylinders passed compression tests. I proceeded to take off the oil pan to check for a possible cracked piston and I found what appears to be timing chain tensioner guide pieces. The vehicle was still running (obviously not running now as the valve covers are off and oil pan is off), could the bank one misfires be a result of a timing chain issue? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, issues with the timing chain tensioner could absolutely cause issues on just one bank.  I'm not completely familiar with your specific engine but typically, each individual bank will have it's own tensioner.  If one tensioner fails, there is no guarantee that bank will remain in time.

Short of actually jumping timing, which if the car passes a compression test, would suggest hasn't happened, it may be that at running RPM (as opposed to cranking for a compression test) that one bank isn't completely in time.  It would be that, with the chain flying around out of tension, that the timing is less than one tooth out but is still out.  With the valve events now not replicating what the crank sensor dictates ought to be happening, rough running / misfiring on that bank only could occur.

I have a strong suspicion that replacing your faulty timing gear ought to resolve your running issues with that bank.

Comment: If your engine has an overhead cam for each bank, one cam could be improperly positioned causing one bank to be out of time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! A tensioner on the right bank (cylinders 1,3,5) was worn out and chipped on one end, causing the bank one chain to skip a tooth! I have ordered a replacement chain!